# Count the number of running process with Telegraf

Tags: monitoring, influxdb, grafana, telegraf, procstat

I'm using telegraf, influxdb and grafana to make a monitoring system for a distributed application. The first thing I want to do is to count the number of java process running on a machine.

But when I make my request, the number of process is nearly random (always between 1 and 8 instead of always having 8).

I think there is a mistake in my telegraf configuration but i don't see where.. I tried to change `interval` but nothing was different : it seems influxdb doesn't have all the data.

I'm running centos 7 and Telegraf v1.5.0 (git: release-1.5 a1668bbf)

All Java process I want to count :

```
[root@localhost ~]# pgrep -f java
10665
10688
10725
10730
11104
11174
16298
22138
```

My telegraf.conf :

```
[global_tags]

# Configuration for telegraf agent
[agent]
  interval = "5s"
  round_interval = true
  metric_batch_size = 1000
  metric_buffer_limit = 10000
  collection_jitter = "0s"
  flush_interval = "10s"
  flush_jitter = "0s"
  precision = ""
  debug = true
  quiet = false
  logfile = "/var/log/telegraf/telegraf.log"
  hostname = "my_server"
  omit_hostname = false
```

My input.conf :

```
# Read metrics about disk usagee
[[inputs.disk]]
  fielddrop = [ "inodes*" ]
  mount_points=["/", "/workspace"]                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  

# File
[[inputs.filestat]]
  files = ["myfile.log"]

# Read the number of running java process
[[inputs.procstat]]
  user = "root"
  pattern = "java"
```

My request :

[image: request]

The response :

[image: response]

Comment: I have tested with `exe` and `process_name` instead of `pattern` and I have the same random result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to count PID, it's a good way to use `exec` like this :

```
[[inputs.exec]]
  commands = ["pgrep -c java"] #command to execute
  name_override = "the_name"   #database's name
  data_format = "my_value"     #colunm's name
```

For `commands`, use `pgrep -c java` without option `-f` because it's "full" and also counts the command `pgrep` (and you have almost the same problem as if you use procstat).

Solution found [here](https://community.influxdata.com/t/solved-count-the-number-of-running-process-with-telegraf/3972/5)

Answer (score 1):

With pattern matching, if it matches multi pids, multi data points are generated with identical tags and timestamp. When these points are sent to influxdb, only the last point is stored.

Example of what may happen with your configuration:

```
00:00 => pid 1
00:05 => pid 2
00:10 => pid 1
00:15 => pid 5
00:20 => pid 7
00:25 => pid 3
00:30 => pid 3
00:35 => pid 4
00:40 => pid 6
00:45 => pid 7
00:50 => pid 6
00:55 => pid 5
Different pids over one minute = 7 (pid 8 was not stored a single time)
```

Since it's random, you sometimes hit the 8 different pids in a minute, but most of the time you don't.

---

To differentiate between processes whose tags are otherwise the same, use `pid_tag = true` :

```
[[inputs.procstat]]
  user = "root"
  pattern = "java"
  pid_tag = true
```

---

However, if you just want to count the number of processes (and don't care about the stats), just use the [exec](https://github.com/influxdata/telegraf/tree/master/plugins/inputs/exec) plugin with a custom command like `pgrep -c -f java`. This will be more optimized than having multiples time series (with pid_tag you end up with one per pid).

Comment: I tried your solutions. I didn't manage to run the one with pid_tag = true. But the second solution almost work. But some times I have the correct process number, some times I have the correct process number + 1. It probably comes from pgrep but I don't see how to fix it.